# Lyft OAuth not resolving with user and application data

Tags: lyft-api

Is anyone else experiencing [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbCx4.jpg) with the Lyft oauth flow? It appears to have happened after they pushed some changes to the flow today.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seeing this error also.  Seems busted.